# CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ECR Repo Image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-ecr

I have pushed a docker image in an ECR Repo  in SourceAccount.

I have deployed a codepipeline in the SourceAccount.

When that codepipeline is run, it deploys ECS stack in TargetAccount. In that stack, ECS tasks are created with containers using the above said image from SourceAccount. However, those tasks remain pending and moved to stopped state ultimately. They show the following error:

```
Status reason   CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for <SourceAccountId>.dkr.ecr.<Region>.amazonaws.com/<RepoName>, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Please advise how to pull images from SourceAccount ECR and create ECS tasks in TargetAccount.

Note:

1) When I push the same image in the ECR of TargetAccount, everything works fine. ECS tasks fail to run only when trying to pull images from another account.

2) The stack rolled back with the following error:

```
Service arn:aws:ecs:<Region>:<TargetAccount>:service/<ServiceName> did not stabilize.
```

Comment: Did you refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-pull-ecr-image.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following policy to the ECR repo in SourceAccount:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowCrossAccountPull",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<TargetAccount>:root"
      },
      "Action": "ecr:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is this required, even if both accounts are the same?

Answer (score 3):

As specified on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-pull-ecr-image.html, you need to specify the AWS account id, when you use `docker pull`:

> docker pull aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazonlinux:latest

Comment: I don't run docker pull command manually.I create an ECS TaskDefinition using CloudFormation and link an image from ECR Repo of another account. When tasks are created from that TaskDefinition, they remain pending and fail ultimately as they can't pull images from another account. When the images are in the same account, everything works fine.